# Не меняется ip-адресс при использовании прокси, сам синтаксис верный. Заранее благодарю за помощь

Tags: python, requests, ip, proxy

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bp
import requests as req

url='https://2ip.ru/'
proxy={"http" :'http://ip-adress:port'}

resp=req.get(url, proxies=proxy)
soup=bp(resp.text, 'lxml')
myip=soup.find('div', class_='ip').text.strip()
print(myip)
```

Использую бесплатные прокси-сервера. Раньше смена айпи отображалась, но сейчас постоянно выдаёт мой настоящий айпи.
Не могу понять в чём дело

Answer (score 2):

Нужно указать http**s**, потому что http и https - разные протоколы. 
параметр proxies - словарь `{'протокол': 'прокси-сервер'}`

```
proxy={'https': 'http://ip-adress:port'}
```

Comment: Алексей, благодарю за ответ. Я изменил на https, но теперь с каждым прокси возникает одна и та же ошибка - HTTPSConnectionPool(host='2ip.ru', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1125)')))